# Macro to replace Characters with Unicode Code working partially only

Tags: vba, utf-8, ms-word, utf-16

I wrote a macro to change Arabic letters to their corresponding UTF code, and add a prefix and suffix to them. I want to use this macro for further development.

For example, the word `كلمة` will need to be changed:

`&#x0643;&#x0644;&#x0645;&#x0629;`

This means that every Arabic letter got a `&#x` before its unicode number, and then got a `;` after it.

I wrote the macro below, which works perfectly for the characters whose code is all numbers, e.g. `0627` or `0628`. But for the letters that has an English letter, the macro does not work. e.g. `062A` and `062B`. Whether I wrote it `062a` or `062A` both don't work.

I need help to locate the error in the macro that makes it works only for the letters with all-numbers unicode block, while doesn't work with the other letters.

Thanks in advance.

```
Sub test1()
'
' test1 Macro
'
'
Dim characters_to_find_list As String
characters_to_find_list = "0627,0623,0625,0628,062A,062B,062C"

Dim characters_to_replace_list As String
characters_to_replace_list = "0627,0623,0625,0628,062A,062B,062C"

Dim characters_to_find As Variant
characters_to_find = Split(characters_to_find_list, ",")

Dim characters_to_replace As Variant
characters_to_replace = Split(characters_to_replace_list, ",")

For i = 0 To UBound(characters_to_find)

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

With Selection.Find

.Text = ChrW("&H" & Val(characters_to_find(i)))
.Replacement.Text = "&#x" & ("&H" & Val(characters_to_replace(i)) & ";")
.Forward = True
.Wrap = wdFindContinue
.Format = True
.MatchCase = True
.MatchWholeWord = False
.MatchKashida = False
.MatchDiacritics = False
.MatchAlefHamza = True
.MatchControl = False
.MatchWildcards = False
.MatchSoundsLike = False
.MatchAllWordForms = False

End With

Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

Next i


End Sub
```

**EDIT:**
Here is a sample text made up of the characters I have in the macro as a test (the full macro will contain all the Arabic Alphabet):

`ا أ ب ا ت إ ث  أ ج  ا أ ب ا ت إ ث  أ ج  ا أ ب ا ت إ ث  أ ج  ا أ ب ا ت إ ث  أ ج  ا أ ب ا ت إ ث  أ ج  ا أ ب ا ت إ ث  أ ج`.

Here is the result after running my macro, you can see that some characters did not convert. The characters that did not convert are the ones with English letters in their Unicode block:

[image: Test Results]

[The Unicode block of each Arabic letter is present in this Wikipedia page. please click here to see it.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_script_in_Unicode) Any character with English Letters in it, will not convert using my macro.

As an example:
Letter `ا` (top left hand corner of the table) has unicode `0623`, it converts correctly, while letter `ت`(third row in the table) has unicode `062A`, it will not convert.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide some sample text that contains problem characters, and give us the corresponding Unicode values. Otherwise, only people who use Arabic can test, which severely limits the pool of possible helpers... Please use the [edit] link to include the information *in* the question (not in a comment).

Comment: @Cindy Meister. Thanks. I added examples, explanation and a link to the full unicode map.

Answer (score 2):

Unicode can be represented in Word VBA using the hex codes such as `062A` or as a decimal number equivalent such as `1579`.

One way to determine the decimal number equivalent is to select the character in Word then run in the Immediate Window (ctrl+G in the VBA Editor):

```
?AscW(Selection.text)
```

Another is to calculate it or use a converter.

This value can then be used as the Find text:

```
With Selection.Find
  .Text = ChrW(1579)
  'and so on...
```

Comment: Thanks @Cindy. I am creating this macro to convert the text to hex code to be able to use it in Notepad++ macros. I don't have control to change the Notepad++ macro system from hex code to decimal. I was hoping for a solution that utilizes the hex code. Thanks.

Comment: If you search using the decimal you can still replace with the hex? Set it up in a dicationary or an array. Or use code to calculate the one from the other...